# Prevent jsp redirect

Tags: jsp

In my application, entering client info is optional. If entering it is mandatory, the user gets a popup, and is later directed to set config page. If not, they only see a Set config icon. I have the below jsp code for this where I basically give a popup to the client to enter their details if the boolean enterInfo is true. If the user doesn't have the privilege, they see the setting the config icon. However, in my case, if the user doesn't have the privilege, they are still seeing the set config page. I only want them to see the icon. I have never used jsp before, so please go easy on the downvotes/comments ;)

Here is the jsp code -

```
    <%if(myenrollment){         
    boolean isPrivUser = FetchInfo.isPrivUser();%>                          
    <div class="showBrowser" style="display:block"><img src="<%= iphoneIcon %>" height="250px" width="250px"></div>
      <%if(isPrivUser) %>
      <div class="textSize" style="font-size:50;font-family:Helvetica;"><p><b>Entering the details</b></p></div>
    <%}else {%>
        <img src="<%=profileIcon%>" height="100px" width="100px" style="margin-top: 20px;">
        <div class="textSize" style="font-size:40;font-family:Times new roman;"><p><b>Setting the config..</b></p></div>
     <%} %>
```

Comment: My off shore team guy suggests I pass a URL as a parameter with the user. I am not clear with what he means here. I know its a little vague, but this is all he says. Any thoughts?

Comment: Anyone? Need your expert advise here please.

Comment: `<%if(isPrivUser) %>` - open & close tags appropriately. It's not complete java code, that the next line will be covered by the If condition.

Comment: @coding_idiot - Where is the mistake here? Can you please specify?